# how to identify an object appears homogenously white

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a segmented image. i need to verify the intensity variation of the ellipse like structure present in the image. I need to check whether that ellipse is homogeneously white

original image
 [image]

ellipse like structure is inside the rectangle
[image]

my segmented image is
[image]

i want to compare the original image (which is homogeneous white) with the segmented region.

Comment: At the very least you need to define "homogeneously white" well enough so that someone understands your question. One image where it *is*, and another example where it *is not* would help. Also, we don't solve problems from scratch for you here, but help you solve your own problems. So the question needs your code so far, and an explanation of where you are stuck.

Comment: So where's this "ellipse" in the image?  We're already having trouble figuring out what that is, so how do you expect to create code that does something that we ourselves have no idea on what the gold standard is?

Comment: You have a segmented (binary) image, and you want to look at the variation of pixel values in the original (greyscale) image within those regions only?

Comment: @nkjt yes i want to check the variation at the segmented region of original image

Comment: @neil how to check the homogeneous white of an obect

Comment: @abcd in that case, `regionprops`. Writing up proper answer, hold on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`regionprops` is perfect for this sort of task. You can pass it your segmented binary image, and your original image to retrieve a list of the pixels in each region (presuming each region is not connected, as shown in your sample image). These will be in the form of a `n x 1` vector for each region, returned as a struct array.

```
stats = regionprops(BW, I, 'PixelValues');
```

(You may want to retrieve other values returned by `regionprops`, like `BoundingBox` or `Centroid`, to help identify which set of pixels belongs to which region more easily. Consult the documentation to see what options are available.).

You can then define some statistical function to show the variation within each region, for example, to calculate the variance and standard deviation for each:

```
for n = 1:length(stats)
    stats(n).var = var(stats(n).PixelValues);
    stats(n).std = std(stats(n).PixelValues);
end
```

If you have some other specific definition of "intensity variation" in mind, then you need to develop some function that calculates it, then just call that instead of a built in like `var` or `std`.